# Exchange server rule to export incoming mail attachments to external folder

Tags: email, exchange-2003, email-server, biztalk, biztalk-2009

I wrote a [question in Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9365089/exchange-server-rule-to-export-incoming-mail-attachments-to-external-folder) and they referenced me here, I hope you can help me.

I would like to make an Exchange Server Rule in order to export incoming mail attachments to a scpecific folder (say "C:\temp")

I have seen this can be done with a Client rule, here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324568/en-us

but I need it to be done unattended

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in functionality to do what you're looking for. You could code an Event Sink that would do what you want, but your code won't work on future versions of Exchange. You'd really be better off having a client program connected to Exchange (either Outlook in MAPI mode, or an IMAP client) handling this because you'd, at least, have compatibility with future Exchange versions.